# How to maintain state of silverlight application on browser back button?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have silverlight control hosted on web page. When I explore this control and go to some other web page, when I come back to same page using back button I want to maintain the same state of the control as before I went to another page.

How this be done?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
-Shwetank

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsolatedStorage to create persistent data for your control in client's computer.